# Does pyodbc execute commands like "select columnA*2 where columnB!=0 from tableA into tableB" locally or remotely?

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc for generating new tables in a remote SQL server. I wrote the following code, replacing column names, table names, driver name, and server name with dummy names.

```
import pyodbc
query="select columnA*2 where columnB!=0 from tableA into tableB"
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={driverA};''Server=serverA;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

I wonder when I run this this code in my Jupyter notebook (I am not sure if running it in a Jupyter Notebook is relevant, but I figure it doesn't hurt to mention it), does my laptop execute some parts of the code or does my laptop send all these code to serverA and ask serverA to execute the command?

What about the following code? Does my laptop simply send the code to the server and wait for the response? Alternatively, does my laptop asks for the entire tableA and then do some of the computing locally?

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver= {driverA};" "Server=serverA;" "Database=databaseA;" 
                          "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
diagramFinal = pd.read_sql("""select columnA*2 where columnB!=0 from tableA""", cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

I read through this [documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki) without finding relevant information. So, I wonder if someone could help me with figuring it out.

Comment: Always on the server

Comment: @nbk Do you care to explain how I could verify this?

Comment: run the log on the server, so you can check it, alternative is running wireshark to log all traffic

Answer (score 0):

Pyodbc is basically just a way for you to send SQL queries to a database. SQL get's executed by the database, so whichever computer hosts your database is the one that will do all the calculations. You just send it the query, the database calculates what data you were looking for and sends that back to you. No computing is done on your end.